# Email server mailgun not relaying messages

Tags: email

Mailgun is not relaying the emails coming from through the spamexperts.com filter.

The destination server (mailgun) set for this domain is not allowing relaying for this domain:

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

```
~ # telnet mxa.mailgun.org 25
Trying 104.130.177.23...
Connected to mxa.mailgun.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ak47 ESMTP ready
helo filtering-server.example.org
250 ak47
mail from:<>
250 2.0.0 OK
rcpt to:<my-address@example.com>
550 5.7.1 Relaying denied
quit
221 See you later. Yours truly, Mailgun
```

Comment: What did mailgun support say about this?

Comment: I think his problem is he's sending from his app, to spamexperts, to mailgun...I suspect mailgun wants authentication and spamexperts isn't configured or isn't able to do so.